# Flutter Firestore Get a stream of each entry out of a map

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have stored a map in Firestore.
Now I would like to receive a stream for every single entry (training) in this map.
Is there a possible way to do this.

[image]

Maybe like in the following, but here my stream just contains 1 Future, because of one document:

```dart
    Stream<CalendarEvent> getTrainings() {
      return _firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc('${_authentication.getUID()}')
        .collection('user')
        .doc('trainings')
        .snapshots()
        .map((doc) => CalendarEvent.fromJson(doc.data()));
    }
```

Here is the code of CalendarEvent where a use the factory constructor to generate instances of calendar event,

```dart
        class CalendarEvent {
          final String title;
          final String id;
          final String date;

          CalendarEvent({this.title, this.id, this.date});

          Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
            Map<String, dynamic> map = {
              'title': title,
              'id': id,
              'date': date,
            };
          }

          //Here we generate user object out of firestore
          factory CalendarEvent.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
            return CalendarEvent(
              title: 'null',
              id: 'null',
              date:'null'
            );
          }

        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the code for `CalendarEvent`? And also, please clarify what you mean by "here my stream just contains 1 Future."

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, I have edited the question. With "here my stream just contains one Future" I mean, that the factory constructor just get triggered one time and not 2 times for each training @VictorEronmosele

Comment: Okay, great! Can you update the screenshot to show the collection that encloses the "trainings" map?

Comment: Did it @VictorEronmosele

Comment: Okay, check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually get the trainings map from the document snapshot and then map that into a Stream of List like below:

```dart
Stream<List<CalendarEvent>> getTrainings() {
  return _firestore
      .collection('users')
      .doc('${_authentication.getUID()}')
      .collection('user')
      .doc('trainings')
      .snapshots()
      .map((doc) {
    Map<String, dynamic> trainingsMap = doc.data()['trainings'];
    return trainingsMap.entries.map((mapEntry) {
      Map<String, dynamic> json = {'id': mapEntry.key, ...mapEntry.value};

      return CalendarEvent.fromJson(json);
    }).toList();
  });
}
```

And update your CalendarEvent.fromJson to this:

```dart
factory CalendarEvent.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
  return CalendarEvent(
    title: json['trainingsName'],
    id: json['id'],
    date: json['trainingsDate']
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts so far. With this code I have also the problem, that the factory constructor CalendarEvent also just get triggered one time, with the first training.
This is the output, if I print json in factory constructor:

{id: training1630414025651636, trainingsDate: Timestamp(seconds=1630414025, nanoseconds=651000000), trainingsName: Training}

Comment: Okay, what shows up when you print `trainingsMap` in the `getTrainings` function?

Comment: Then I get the whole map with both trainings.
{training1630414025651636: {trainingsDate: Timestamp(seconds=1630414025, nanoseconds=651000000), trainingsName: Training}, training1630414026958419: {trainingsDate: Timestamp(seconds=1630414026, nanoseconds=957999000), trainingsName: Training}}

Comment: Check the result of `getTrainings()` and see if it contains the two trainings. `getTrainings.listen((trainingList) => print(trainingList))`

Comment: This is the output:

[Instance of 'CalendarEvent', Instance of 'CalendarEvent']

Comment: So that means the method works properly. Not sure why the print in the factory method only runs once though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236608/discussion-between-duke-of-coding-and-victor-eronmosele).